# subscriber (for a custom event) doesn't exist. backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

There's `HeaderView` view in my application. According to what route has been fired the view gets a custom heading. The view's subscribed to `headerview:titleChanged` event.

**headerview.js**

```
var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#header-region'),
    initialize: function() {
        bus.on('headerview:titleChanged', function(args) {
            this.setTitle(args.title);
        }, this);
        this.render();
    },
    setTitle: function(title) { this.$el.find('.title').html(title); },
    render: function() { return this; }
});
```

at **router.js**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() { this.route('', 'defaultRoute'); }
});

// trying to create it before AppRouter even got initialized
new HeaderView();

var appRouter = new AppRouter();
appRouter.on('route:defaultRoute', function() { 
    _routeHandlers.renderDefaultContentRegion(); 
});

Backbone.history.start();
```

at **router.js, _routeHandlers.renderDefaultContentRegion()**

```
// trying to send message
bus.trigger('headerview:titleChanged', {title: 'heading text'});
```

The problem is that *router* gets created first and *header view* gets created next and as the result there's no `headerview:titleChanged` recipient.

Is it possible to render `HeaderView` before default route gets fired? How do I handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HeaderView` is presumably an essential part of the application so it should be created during application start up, the problem is getting the order right. You could hijack `AppRouter#initialize` to be your application constructor and let it create the `HeaderView` at the right time:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.route('', 'defaultRoute');
        new HeaderView();
        bus.trigger('headerview:titleChanged', {title: 'heading text'});
    }
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/dpSbB/

Alternatively, you could move all the initialization into a separate application constructor and let that line things up in the right order. This also gives you a convenient place to put global things (such as your event bus) without worrying about polluting the global namespace. Something like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.route('', 'defaultRoute');
    },
    //...
});

var app = {
    bus: _({}).extend(Backbone.Events),
    initialize: function() {
        new HeaderView;
        new AppRouter;
        app.bus.trigger('headerview:titleChanged', {title: 'heading text'});
        Backbone.history.start();        
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/eLyys/

Comment: The other problem is that when application starts at route other than default message gets overwritten. Do you have any thoughts.

Comment: I didn't know that default route handler gets called anyway: whether you start at some route say `/app/#sample_route` or at default route

Comment: @brick: Did you figure those questions out? Sorry, your comments got lost along the way.

Comment: Not yet. At jsfiddle it works pretty fine. I've tried to add additional route handler and it worked to me. at `show` mode even after refreshing it showed expected text. In my environment this doesn't happen. I'm going to strip away all unnecessary code and, reproduce the error.